# Specify alsa device name or aloop for system ouput audio to be used as input in ffmpeg command

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, alsa, ffmpeg

I am using Debian 9 with its version of ffmpeg. This is my `ffmpeg` command I use to screen record:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 4096 -f alsa -i plughw:CARD=Device,DEV=0 -thread_queue_size 4096 \
-f alsa -i default -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first -thread_queue_size 4096 \
-f x11grab -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -i $DISPLAY+1920,0 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -preset veryfast \
-c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 96k -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

I am able to successfully record my system sounds and microphone at the same time. However, I first need to open `pavucontrol` and make sure the system audio is set to default on the Input Devices tab. I would like to be able to use the specific device name for system sounds as I do for my microphone with `plughw:CARD=Device,DEV=0`. However, I am not sure what should be used. For system sounds, using `-f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor` works, but there is about a 15 second delay in the recorded video file. So, I would need to use `-f alsa -i $device_name`.

Here is the output of `pacmd list-sources`:

```
2 source(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_input.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.analog-mono>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9049
    volume: mono: 63923 /  98% / -0.65 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 19944 /  30% / -31.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 1.85 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 48000Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "USB PnP Audio Device"
        alsa.long_card_name = "USB PnP Audio Device at usb-0000:00:10.1-1, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:10.1-usb-0:1:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.1/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "0c76"
        device.vendor.name = "JMTek, LLC."
        device.product.id = "161e"
        device.product.name = "USB PnP Audio Device"
        device.serial = "0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device"
        device.string = "hw:2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "192000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "96000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-mono"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Mono"
        device.description = "USB PnP Audio Device Analog Mono"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.components = "USB0c76:161e"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-mic>
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 1950
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1999.82 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 3 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    module: 9
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfeb00000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "780d"
        device.product.name = "FCH Azalia Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

Here is the output of `arecord -L`:

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Front speakers
dmix:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Generic,DEV=2
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Alt Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Generic,DEV=2
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Alt Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=2
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Alt Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=2
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Alt Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Device
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=U0x46d0x825
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

I have also tried using `-f alsa -i loopout` as mentioned [here](https://youtu.be/sIs0-6F08Us?t=490). I first enabled the ALSA `aloop` kernel module with: `insmod /lib/modules/4.9.0-8-amd64/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-aloop.ko`. It loaded properly:

```
~$ lsmod | grep aloop
snd_aloop              24576  6
snd_pcm               110592  10 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_aloop
snd                    86016  35 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_aloop,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
```

However, I received an error when trying to record with ffmpeg:
`[alsa @ 0x55bd6922ee40] cannot open audio device loopout (No such file or directory)
loopout: Input/output error`.
Using the loopout (or perhaps it is loopback?) might be most ideal because it is my understanding that this would capture any system sound no matter the hardware device.

So, to summarize I would like to be able to use ALSA to capture any system output sounds during screen capture, no matter which card or device is default at the time.